# Expect one view Pop other

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to pop the view from stack. On one condition, Except my home view and toolbar I like to pop all views when I am trying to push new view.

```
viewpop: function() {
    v = Ext.getCmp('homeViewPort');
    viewExist = v.items;
    for (viewExist = 0; v < viewExist.length; v++) {
        if (v.items.items[3].id != "ext-titlebar-2" && v.items.items[3].id != "homeView") {
            v.pop(3);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: First of all, what is your question? Secondly, in your code, you assign something to `viewExist` just to write over it in the for cycle and over the `v` too. Try `for (var i = 0; i < viewExist.length; i++) {` and see where that gets you.

Comment: @MarthyM Expect one view i have to pop other.

Comment: Could you supply us with a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pravnviji/swh6fazp/